# Does Google Play Services needs to be implemented for getting updates for a App?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I want to know if I don't implement the Google Play Service then the updates for the app will be available to the user or not?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement Google Play Services to make updates available for the users. All you have to do is to prepare a new version (with an updated `versionCode`) of your app and upload it to the Play store.

Comment: Actually i am asking about the update available notification to the user.

Comment: Do you mean the normal notifications you receive from Google Play for each app or something more special?

Comment: Yes.I am asking this as per the Automatic Updates Point of this link http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html

Comment: This is about the updates to Google Play Services itself, not your app.

Comment: One more thing I am using Google Play Add Service for showing add and for this do I need the service to be available to the device?

Comment: I'm not sure about that... I'm using AdMob.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43817/discussion-between-kousik-and-szymon)

Answer (score 0):

No, if you publish your application on Google Play, not necessary to use Google Play Services to publish your app updates. Actually, Play Store(Android Market) takes a very good care of updating your application. Users are notified as soon as your update is available, and if they decide to ignore the notification, it's their decision.

What you need to take care is upgrade you application [version](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html),  with and updated `versionCode` on the manifest, like below `android:versionCode="2"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.package.name"
      android:versionCode="2"
      android:versionName="1.1">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

- If you want to handle update stuff in your own, then you can try the following lib on [gitHub (cwac-updater)](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-updater). Below is note from repo.

> <kbd>Updater</kbd> is a library designed to allow your app to be self-updating. While the library ships with a stock implementation of things like detecting a new version and downloading that new APK, you can plug in your own implementations (e.g., do all this over the corporate VPN).

Comment: actually I am asking because of the automatic updates point of this link http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html

Comment: Please read the note from wiki, you can get a clear view, don't worry- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Play_Services